# Cannot Get error in Node.js with angular

Tags: node.js, angular, server

I am getting data from angular and everything works fine as I expected. I get values from angular and can store into my local dB. But I just realized, when I actually go onto the backend server in the web browser its shows as below,

> Cannot GET

It seems like server is receiving data without any problem but why does it show this error?

**backend**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var sql = require('mssql');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.all("/*", function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
  next();
});


app.listen(1433, function () { console.log('Example app listening on port 1433!') })

var config = {
  server: "",
  database: "",
  user: "",
  password: "",
  port: 1433
};

app.post('/ping', function (req, res) {
  res.send(res.body);})
```

**angular4**

```
this.appService.http.post('http://localhost:1433/ping', getAll, { headers: Headers })
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data), (err) => console.error("Failed! " + err);
      })
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on an API meant to be consumed in your website is very risky. Don't do it in production - limit the allowed access for cross origin resource sharing to domains you recognize.

Comment: Also `res.body` should be `req.body` you have a typo

Answer (score 0):

Use rest api clients to manually fire http requests. For example [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to fire HTTP POST request. Otherwise define HTTP GET request in your server this will response to your manual browser request.

For example, Define a method in sever as follows:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello Ding Dong !!!');  
});
```

Comment: updated the answer, You have define the post in backend, How do you send post request from browser?